# css, ошибка при подключении шрифта font-face

Tags: css, шрифты

Добрый день

При подключении шрифта выдаёт фот такую ошибку

> Failed to decode downloaded font: http://petanium.ru/mobile/fonts/tauruh.ttf
>   start.php:1 OTS parsing error: cmap: expected search range != search range (32 != 16)

Можно ли это как то исправить?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Использовал сервис [для конвертации шрифтов](http://www.font2web.com/)
И всё починилось.